# How to get form data from login screen into a usable string in my controller in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I feel as if this should be something very easy but I cannot figure it out, I have everything working I just need to make the 'email' and 'password' fields change to whatever the user enters. Below is my controller where the data gets sent via HTTP

```
 postData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http
          .post(Uri.parse("http://exampleIP/untitled/authentication/login.php"), body: {
        "username": 'email',   // needs to be what user inputs//
        "password": 'password' // needs to be what user inputs//
```

I understand all the code is not there but the code works I just need to know how to get the input from the form

Here is form code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_feather_icons/flutter_feather_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutx/flutx.dart';
import 'package:harralander/images.dart';
import 'package:harralander/theme/app_theme.dart';


import '../controllers/login_controller.dart';

class LogInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LogInScreenState createState() => _LogInScreenState();
}

class _LogInScreenState extends State<LogInScreen> {
  late ThemeData theme;
  late CustomTheme customTheme;

  late LogInController controller;
  late OutlineInputBorder outlineInputBorder;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    theme = AppTheme.theme;
    customTheme = AppTheme.customTheme;

    controller = FxControllerStore.putOrFind(LogInController());
    outlineInputBorder = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FxBuilder<LogInController>(
        controller: controller,
        builder: (controller) {
          return _buildBody();
        });
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: FxSpacing.x(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            FxText.h3(
              'Log In',
              fontWeight: 700,
            ),
            FxSpacing.height(20),
            Form(
              key: controller.formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    style: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                        filled: true,
                        isDense: true,
                        fillColor: customTheme.card,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          FeatherIcons.mail,
                          color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                        hintText: "Email Address",
                        enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                        focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                        border: outlineInputBorder,
                        contentPadding: FxSpacing.all(16),
                        hintStyle: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                        isCollapsed: true),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    controller: controller.emailTE,
                    validator: controller.validateEmail,
                    cursorColor: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                  ),
                  FxSpacing.height(20),
                  TextFormField(
                    style: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                        filled: true,
                        isDense: true,
                        fillColor: customTheme.card,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          FeatherIcons.lock,
                          color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                        hintText: "Password",
                        enabledBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                        focusedBorder: outlineInputBorder,
                        border: outlineInputBorder,
                        contentPadding: FxSpacing.all(16),
                        hintStyle: FxTextStyle.b2(),
                        isCollapsed: true),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    controller: controller.passwordTE,
                    validator: controller.validatePassword,
                    cursorColor: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            FxSpacing.height(20),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: FxButton.text(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.goToForgotPasswordScreen();
                  },
                  padding: FxSpacing.zero,
                  splashColor: customTheme.fitnessPrimary.withAlpha(40),
                  child: FxText.b3(
                    'Forgot password ?',
                    color: customTheme.fitnessPrimary,
                  )),
            ),
            FxSpacing.height(20),
            Row(
              children: [
                FxButton(
                    padding: FxSpacing.xy(16, 12),
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.postData();
                    },
                    backgroundColor: customTheme.card,
                    splashColor: theme.colorScheme.onBackground.withAlpha(40),
                    elevation: 0,
                    borderRadiusAll: 4,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Image(
                          image: AssetImage(Images.google),
                          height: 17,
                          width: 17,
                        ),
                        FxSpacing.width(20),
                        FxText.l2(
                          'Login with Google',
                          fontWeight: 600,
                          color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                FxSpacing.width(20),
                Expanded(
                  child: FxButton(
                    padding: FxSpacing.y(12),
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.postData();
                    },
                    backgroundColor: customTheme.fitnessPrimary,
                    elevation: 0,
                    borderRadiusAll: 4,
                    child: FxText.b2(
                      'Log In',
                      color: customTheme.fitnessOnPrimary,
                      fontWeight: 600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            FxSpacing.height(20),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                FxText.b3(
                  'New to Harralander? ',
                ),
                FxButton.text(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.goToRegisterScreen();
                    },
                    padding: FxSpacing.zero,
                    splashColor: customTheme.fitnessPrimary.withAlpha(40),
                    child: FxText.b3(
                      'Register',
                      color: customTheme.fitnessPrimary,
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your **LogInController** declare a **TextEditingController**

xample:

```
  class LogInController extends GetxController{
 // xample as your textediting as this
 final emailTE = TextEditingController() 
     , passwordTE = TextEditingControler();

 callToLoging() async{
    //validate first as you use formKey
   if(formKey.currentState!.validate()){
        //call the loginApiService 
        await LoginApiService.postData(
            email: emailTE.value!.text // or email!.text,
            password : passwordTE.value!.text // or password!.text,
             );
      }
  }


  }

  class LoginAPIService{
    
  //Use Future or static it depends on you
  static postData({String? email , String? password}) async {
        try {
          var response = await http
              .post(Uri.parse("http://exampleIP/untitled/authentication/login.php"), body: {
            "username": email ?? "",   // needs to be what user inputs//
            "password": password ?? ""});
       } catch(e){
          
       }
    }
   
  }
```

mention me if something happens if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

**you have to TextEditingController to get user input, and store those in varibale or access through using .text method.
Eg:**

```
TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();

String? uName;
String? pwd;

//inside from:
//we can get data using 
uName = _emailController.text;
pwd = _passwordController.text;
//or we can pass this directly as a parameter like this:
_passwordController.text
```

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterloginform/validation.dart';

```
class LoginFormWithAutoValidation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginFormWithAutoValidationState createState() => _LoginFormWithAutoValidationState();
}

class _LoginFormWithAutoValidationState extends State<LoginFormWithAutoValidation> {

  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);
  
  TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email;
  String _password;
 

  bool _autoValidate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[400],
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              color: Color(0xffF3F3F3),
              elevation: 5,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      Center(
                          child: Text(
                        "Your Logo Here",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),
                      )),
                      SizedBox(height: 25.0),

             // TextFormField for email address

                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        autofocus: false,
                        controller: _emailController,
                        validator: validateEmail,
                        onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
                        style: style,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                         contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                          hintText: "Email",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                           borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 25.0),

            // TextFormField for email address

                      TextFormField(
                        autofocus: false,
                        controller: _passwordController,
                        validator: validatePassword,
                        onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
                        style: style,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                         contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                         hintText: "Password",
                         border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 25.0),

                      Divider(color: Colors.black),      // divider

                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),

                      Material(                   // login button
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                 padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                          onPressed: () {


                            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              Navigator.push(context,
                               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                return LoginFormWithAutoValidation();
                              }));
                            } else {
                              setState(() {                    
                             // validation error
                                _autoValidate = true;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          child: Text("Login",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```